# error C3861: 'D3DCompileFromFile': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, direct3d, directx-11

I'm trying to use the D3D function D3DCompilFromFile and it was working completely fine until I tweaked my shader a bit and now all of a sudden my program has stopped recognizing the D3DCompileFromFile function, I have checked what header/libraries/dll's I need to include and they are all there to my knowledge.

I'm using VS2013

Here is some example code

application.cpp

```
HRESULT Application::CompileShaderFromFile(WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    // Set the D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* pErrorBlob;
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(szFileName, nullptr, nullptr, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel,
        dwShaderFlags, 0, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (pErrorBlob != nullptr)
            OutputDebugStringA((char*)pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer());

        if (pErrorBlob) pErrorBlob->Release();

        return hr;
    }

    if (pErrorBlob) pErrorBlob->Release();

    return S_OK;
}
```

application.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
#include <directxcolors.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace DirectX;
using namespace std;
.
.
.
.
HRESULT CompileShaderFromFile(WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut);
```

Lighting.fx

```
cbuffer cbData
{
    float4x4 World; 
    float4x4 View; 
    float4x4 Projection;

    float4 gDiffuseMtrl; 
    float4 gDiffuseLight; 
    float3 gLightVecW;
    float4 gAmbientMtrl;
    float4 gAmbientLight;
};

struct VS_IN
{
    float4 posL   : POSITION;
    float3 normalL : NORMAL;
};

struct VS_OUT
{
    float4 Pos    : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Col    : COLOR;
};

VS_OUT VS(VS_IN vIn)
{
    VS_OUT output = (VS_OUT)0;

    output.Pos = mul( vIn.posL, World ); 
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, View ); 
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, Projection );


    // Convert from local to world normal
    float3 normalW = mul(float4(vIn.normalL, 0.0f), World).xyz;
    normalW = normalize(normalW);

    // Compute Colour
    float s = max(dot(gLightVecW, normalW), 0.0f);
    float3 diffuse = s*(gDiffuseMtrl*gDiffuseLight).rgb;
    float3 ambient = gAmbientMtrl * gAmbientLight;
    output.Col.rgb = diffuse + ambient;
    output.Col.a = gDiffuseMtrl.a;


    return output;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUT pIn) : SV_Target
{
    return pIn.Col;
}

technique11 Render
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VS() ) ); SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, PS() ) );
    }
}
```

Sorry if I'm just throwing way too much code at people but I'm really struggling to find out the cause of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the [legacy DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)? `D3DCompileFromFile` did not exist in the old #43 version of [D3DCompiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) which means you are probably picking up the older 'd3dcompiler.h' header in the DirectX SDK rather than the newer Windows 8.1 SDK version of 'd3dcompiler.h' which came with VS 2013.

Ideally you should not use the DirectX SDK at all (see [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)).

I see from your shader you are using Effects 11, so you should be sure to move to latest [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) version which doesn't need any DXSDK header. Be aware that the support for the 'fx_5_0' profile is deprecated and is expected to be removed in a future update of the HLSL compiler. The Windows 8.1 SDK #47 version of the compiler will emit a warning stating this, but will still compile these shaders.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when I go to the definition of D3DCompileFromFile it brings me to d3dcompiler.h file which is located in "Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um", this file also contains

`#define D3DCOMPILER_DLL_W L"d3dcompiler_47.dll"
#define D3DCOMPILER_DLL_A "d3dcompiler_47.dll"`

Which leaves me to believe I'm using the correct compiler file, in my Include and Lib paths I also use the windows 8.1 "include/um" and "Lib\winv6.3\um\x86"

Comment: ah, wait, I think I left the original include pathways in the VC++ Directories tab, now that I've removed them I'm getting an error saying I don't have D3DCOMPILER_46.dll

Comment: #46 was the Windows 8.0 SDK that came with VS 2012. Your VC++ Directories tab should be the defaults (set them all to "inherits from parent.." if they are set to anything else). IF you also need stuff from the legacy DirectX SDK (basically D3DX or XACT), then you need to set Executable to ``$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86`` or ``$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86``, Include to ``$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include``, and Library to ``$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86`` or ``$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64`` for VS 2012 or VS 2013.

Comment: I've tried setting them all to "inherits from parent" but I'm still getting the problem, when I go to the definition of D3DCompileFromFile it says there are two definitions/d3dcompiler.h files, one in the 8.0 folder and one in the 8.1 folder, now I just need to figure out how to include only the 8.1 folder, I've tried telling it to include it alone but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Solved it! It seems that it ran perfectly fine after I renamed the 8.0 folder to something else then ran the program again, it even still works after I've put the 8.0 folder back to its original name.

Thanks a lot!